# How to arrange my data for Friedman's test

Tags: r, friedman-test

I have conducted a study where participants have seen photos of people in different categories, let's call them A, B C, and D, and have ranked four pictures in each category on 1st choice to 4th choice. So essentially in each category there will be four rankings between 1-4 per participant. I want to conduct a Friedman test to see which category is ranked first, second, third and fourth. So far I've calculated the mean ranking per each category per each participant, thus ended up with a 78x4 matrix. I've run the test but I'm now doubting if I should have ran it on the mean rankings. There is technically no ranking of for example, 1.8 so I'm wondering if my results are going to be misleading?

A reproducible data sample

```r
library(tidyverse)

original.dat <- data.frame(sbj = rep(1:4, each =  16),
                           category = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 16),
                           rank = sample(1:4, 64, replace = T))

# Summarised dataset used for analysis

dat <- original.dat %>%
  group_by(sbj, category) %>%
  summarise(m_rank = mean(rank)) %>%
  spread(category, m_rank) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a small error when building the table used to the Friedman's test.

Since you have 4 replicates, you may need to consider each of them individually (and not summarize the average result, as you're doing).

Thus, I recommend you to do the following:

```
original.dat <- data.frame(sbj = rep(1:4, each =  16),
                           replicate = rep(1:4, each = 4),
                           category = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 16),
                           rank = sample(1:4, 64, replace = T))

dat <- original.dat %>%
  group_by(sbj, category,replicate) %>%
  spread(category, rank) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Note that I added a `replicate` column, which was used by `dplyr`.

Then, you can perform the Fridman's test using as input the four columns of this data.frame (A, B, C, and D).  You will get the following data.frame:

[image: result table]

However, the standard R implementation of Friedman's test only accepts a matrix as input. Thus, you may convert your data.frame to a matrix and run the Fridman's test as follows.

```
friedman.test(as.matrix(dat[,3:6]))
```

Hope you get it!

Comment: Right, it's so each subject has their own small 'matrix of 4x4'?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I modified my answer to include a screenshot of the resulting data.frame.

Comment: I ran it and saw it myself, thank you! It's actually close to what the original data looks like.